# Cannot convert object to primitive value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I post data to node server:

```
{
  "form_1": [{
    "resultName": "",
    "level": "",
    "unitOrder": "",
    "winner": "",
    "winnerOrder": "",
    "date": "1",
    "score": ""
  }],
  "form_2": [{
    "resultName": "",
    "level": "",
    "unitOrder": "",
    "winner": "",
    "winnerOrder": "",
    "date": "1",
    "score": ""
  }],
  "form_3": [{
    "resultName": "",
    "level": "",
    "unitOrder": "",
    "winner": "",
    "winnerOrder": "",
    "date": "1",
    "score": ""
  }]
}
```

And I try to console.log the data in express server:

```
console.log(req.body)
```

but there comes the error:

> TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value

I do not understand. so how can I get the data ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24339780/posting-object-array-to-sails-causes-typeerror-cannot-convert-object-to-primit

Comment: I just try to console.log an object, it works well. @Troajan

Answer (score 23):

**The actual reason behind this error**

**when Javascript is trying to cast an object to a string.**

Javascript will try to call the `toString()` method of that object. most of the Javascript objects have `toString()` method inherited from `Object.prototype`. but some of them that have a `null prototype`, not have `toString()` method so the Javascript will fail to convert those objects to a string primitive. and `can't convert object to primitive error will rise`.

**to create a null prototype Object in Javascript use this method**

```js
let travel = Object.create(null);
```

**The solution**

```js
travel = {...travel};
```

Comment: some object has .value :
computed(() => usePage().props.value.<YourData>).value

Answer (score 20):

[console.log](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data_args) is for logging strings or simple values

as the docs say, you can format the output, as a json for example `console.log("body: %j", req.body)`

or, better yet, use [console.dir](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_dir_obj_options) to log the object as it is

Comment: @torazaburo because console.log can't convert it to a primitive value to display. Did you try alebianco's solution?

Comment: which version of node are you using?

Comment: @alebianco v 6.5.0

Answer (score 3):

Points to check.

1. header type should be **application/json**.
2. Check whether json is **stringified**.

angular code

```
 headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(body), { headers: headers }).map((data: Response) => data.json()).catch(this.handleError);
```

3. **Cors** is enabled in server.js in  nodeJs - express code

   var cors = require('cors');
   app.use(cors());

4.Now **req.body** in api.js (or *somefile.js*) should have the json data passed from angular form

Above is the one the *combination* which **worked** for me. Some are facing error by sending a json from angular and trying to parse a json object again in nodejs which cause a error.

Few get **pre-flight** error. Actually the browser might first send a pre-flight request with method OPTIONS to get allowed origins, headers and methods. So enabling cors helps to avoid this error.

Answer (score 1):

What's causing this error-message in general is that the system tries to convert some object to a string but can not produce a string from the object it is trying to display as string.

That is often the case if a value does not inherit Object but is a more primitive type of value so it does not inherit the method toString() from Object.prototype.

For instance

```
Object.create(null) + ''
```

causes this error because + ""  basically means the same as calling the method toString() of the value to which you try to + "". But since Object.create(null) does not inherit the method toString() from Object.prototype this causes an error.

Similarly

```
(Object.create(null)) .toString()
```

produces this same error.

If you add your own method toString() to such a value your added method must return a string or else you get the same error-message again because the system then calls your toString() -method but that does not produce a String.

So beware trying to print out in the log etc. values which are not Objects. Another case would be if you called alert() or confirm() etc. with such a value.